# How to apply double quotes in html code within the body property of emails in VBA?

Tags: html, excel, vba, email, outlook

I have an HTML code that I need to send email to certain sectors of a company.

When I use the `.HTMLbody` property with html, a syntax error arises.

The VBA code and the HTML code that I tried to pass to the `.HTMLbody` property.

```vb
Sub enviar_email()

    Dim linha As Integer
    Dim Objeto_outlook As Object
    Dim Email As Object

    For linha = 3 To 13

        Set Objeto_outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set Email = Objeto_outlook.createitem(0)
        
        texto = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><p>Hi All,<br><br>" & vbCrLf & _
        "Find in" & vbCrLf & _
        "<a href="https://alcoainc.sharepoint.com/sites/GSSFinance/Accoutingprocess/SitePages/Home.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fsites%2FGSSFinance%2FAccoutingprocess%2FShared%20Documents%2F2021%20Chargeback%20%2D%20ADI%27s%2F11%2ENovember%2FEurope%2FNorway&FolderCTID=0x0120000D0C1EF00C57724DB137DE9812EE80D4&View=%7B87CB7C73%2DFB6E%2D415F%2D90A5%2D623BE45360BC%7D">Sharepoint</a> & vbCrLf & _
        "ADIs regarding November chargeback entries to be posted in your region.<br>Could you please post the entries in GL by Tuesday(Nov 16th)?<br><br>If you identify any issue that should be adjusted or any remap to be done, please let us know.<br>Definitions:IICS - transactions between different Countries;<br>Intercompany – transactions between different Legal Entities inside the same Country.<br>Intracompany - transactions between the same Legal Entities and the same Countries.<br>Note that all ADIs were created considering EParent rules.<br><br>Below is your help chain:<br>" & vbCrLf & _
        "Accounting inquires -  Brunorio, Fernanda P.A.; Perna, Denise C.S.<br>Plan inquires - Moreira, Leonardo; Silva, Juliana C.<br>Thank you,<br>Célio Melo.</p></body></html>"

        Email.display
        Email.To = Cells(linha, 7).Value
        Email.cc = Cells(linha, 8).Value
        Email.Subject = Cells(linha, 6).Value
        Email.HTMLbody = texto  'Cells(3, 4).Value
    Next linha
    
End Sub
```

HTML code I'm trying to move to VBA email body property:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Hi All,<br><br>

Find in <a href="https://alcoainc.sharepoint.com/sites/GSSFinance/Accoutingprocess/SitePages/Home.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fsites%2FGSSFinance%2FAccoutingprocess%2FShared%20Documents%2F2021%20Chargeback%20%2D%20ADI%27s%2F11%2ENovember%2FEurope%2FNorway&FolderCTID=0x0120000D0C1EF00C57724DB137DE9812EE80D4&View=%7B87CB7C73%2DFB6E%2D415F%2D90A5%2D623BE45360BC%7D
">Sharepoint</a> ADIs regarding November chargeback entries to be posted in your region.<br>
Could you please post the entries in GL by Tuesday(Nov 16th)?<br><br>
                                                                                                                                                                                          
If you identify any issue that should be adjusted or any remap to be done, please let us know.<br> 

Definitions:
IICS - transactions between different Countries;<br>
Intercompany – transactions between different Legal Entities inside the same Country.<br>
Intracompany - transactions between the same Legal Entities and the same Countries.<br>
Note that all ADIs were created considering EParent rules.<br><br>

Below is your help chain:<br>
Accounting inquires -  Brunorio, Fernanda P.A.; Perna, Denise C.S.<br>
Plan inquires - Moreira, Leonardo; Silva, Juliana C.<br>

Thank you,<br>
Célio Melo.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Making a guess as I can't test - You have double quotes in your HTML (href attribute) which you need to double up so it should be something like: `"<a href=""https://alcoainc.sharepo....%7D"">Sharepoint</a>`

Comment: Thanks @Raymond,  you solve my problem.

Comment: A general rule when you are dealing with strings with double quotes - double them up. If you find it troublesome to insert in manually then copy the string in notepad, find/replace all `"` with `""` then copy-paste back to VBE and enclose with `"`. @DouglasOliveira

Comment: Thanks for Tip @RaymondWu